# Why Android BLE's communication can be accessed by all App?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Thanks a lot for in advance!

From Android's BLE documentation,

[image]

I am aware that Apps would need app-layer security to protect its data.

My questions are:

1. Since app needs to implement its own security, does it also apply to BLE Devices
2. Why does Android allow apps to access all BLE devices? Is it specially designed for some reasons or simply it was originally written this way?

Comment: How should it be done otherwise do you think then, compared to how it is right now? Note that the Bluetooth standard has no concept of "different apps running on a device"; the standard sees each device as one complete unit, and that is probably because that's how it was before the ages of apps.

Comment: You can also use L2CAP CoC instead of GATT, that way you get a "private" communication channel that cannot be eavesdropped by other apps running on the same device.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is present because the pairing process occurs at the operating system level, not within a specific application. This process enables the use of encrypted communications.

To address your questions:

1. If you incorporate application-layer security, your BLE device must adopt the same security protocol. For instance, if you employ an asymmetric encryption such as the RSA algorithm, both devices must implement this algorithm.
2. You could say it's by design, other applications can access all BLE communications because the pairing process is done at the operating system layer.